# Double Click File to Run with Specific Python Script (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, python, script, windows-registry, context-menu

In Windows 10, is it possible to make a file with a specific extension run with a given Python script? For example, I have .pickle files saved, and I wrote a simple Python script to print them out. I would like to double click on the .pickle file and have the Python script that prints it run.

I was able to create a context menu entry that successfully did this. For example, this simple Python script named `view_pickle_file.py`:

```
import pickle
import sys

filename = sys.argv[1]
print(filename)

var = pickle.load(open(filename, 'rb'))

print(type(var))
if type(var) == list:
  print(len(var))
  for ii, value in enumerate(var):
    print(ii, value)
elif type(var) == dict:
  print(len(var))
  for key, val in var.items():
    print(key, val, sep="\t")
elif type(var) == set:
  print(len(var))
  for ii in var:
    print(ii)
else:
  print(var)

input("Press enter")
```

And the registry key at `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.pickle\shell\View\command` with a (Default) REG_SZ Data value of `"C:\Program Files\Python\Python38\python.exe" "C:\Scripts\Python\view_pickle_file.py" "%1"`:

creates:

[image]

which prints out the pickle file perfectly.

But this is a context menu entry. I want to double click the .pickle file to make this happen. How would I do that? Is it possible? Or is the context menu entry as close as I will ever get?

Comment: Try to double the back-slashes in the registry like this : `\\\`.

Comment: @harrymc, I'm not having any issues with the example I showed (the view context menu entry works correctly). The problem is that I don't know how to achieve the same thing by double clicking the file. Is there some registry manipulation I can do to achieve that?

Comment: Does your entry show up in (1) Context menu "Open with", and (2) Default Programs > Associate a file type or protocol with a program > Choose default applications by f‌ile type > .pickle ?

Comment: @harrymc, no it does not. I assume I will need to add some different registry key to make it work by double clicking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this registry update:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.pickle]
@="python.pickle"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\python.pickle]
@="Pickle Document"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\python.pickle\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\python.pickle\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\python.pickle\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\Python\\Python38\\python.exe\" \"C:\\Scripts\\Python\\view_pickle_file.py\" \"%1\""
```

Comment: Excellent! This worked great. Can you explain why the last key isn't the only one required? What's the point of the first two keys instead of just using "[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\pickle\shell\open\command]" for the last one?

Comment: The purpose is to set the display name for "Open with".